# Violated assumptions for regression

Tags: regression, assumptions

I am not sure what to do with this regression residuals.

[image: Regression Diagnostics]

The Normal Q-Q plot is indicating that residuals are non-normal (not too extreme) and residual variance is not constant (not too bad). My input variables are factor variables so I am not able to normalize it.

What do you guys think about this plot? Should I continue with this plot and say that assumptions are not violated and continue?

In fact, I think assumptions are violated slightly but not extremely. What should I do if I think assumptions are violated?

Comment: I didn't know about that!! great !

Comment: It looks to me like you've got a few odd cases (they show in lower left in QQ plot). Those cases should be investigated. If they have errors, that may solve the problem.

Comment: You can't judge normality from the QQplot when the residuals exhibit curvature and the variance isn't constant; with those other assumptions violated the normality isn't readily assessed.

Comment: data:  residuals(fit) W = 0.9554, p-value = 0.000284 But I think for these kind of tests, It is unlikely to not reject the null(H0=normal)